# Does 'session_destroy()' completely destroys and make it unaccessible the super global variable $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, superglobals

I've learnt that

`session_unset()` removes all session variables which means it just clears the `$_SESSION` variable and it’s equivalent to doing:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

This does only affect the local `$_SESSION` variable instance/s.

`session_destroy()` destroys the session data that is stored in the session storage.

My question are as below :

1. Does session  mean the $_SESSION super global variable?
2. When session_destroy() will be called will the super global variable `$_SESSION` also get destroyed and becomes unaccessible?
3. If the super global variable $_SESSION doesn't become unaccessible even after calling `session_destroy()` then what it actually destroys when the session variable instances have already been destroyed by `session_unset()` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

session_unset() does not destroy the session, session_unset should be used on a single session variable.

```
session_unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
```

**Does session mean the $_SESSION super global variable?**

According to php docs do not use session_unset on the global variable [http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php][1]

> Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will
>   disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION
>   superglobal.

**When session_destroy() will be called will the super global variable $_SESSION also get destroyed and becomes unaccessible?**

No it does not become unaccessible. After destroying a session with session_destroy() you can use session_start() to create a new session.

**If the super global variable $_SESSION doesn't become unaccessible even after calling session_destroy() then what it actually destroys when the session variable instances have already been destroyed by session_unset() ?**

calling session_unset should be used to remove individual session variables, not to destroy your session. After using session_unset the session is still active, you can see from my test below:

```
<?php
    // This prints "Active"
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1000;
    session_unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    if(session_status()==2)
        echo "Active \n";
```

To destroy a session in php, I don't recommend trying to use session_unset. I do:

```
// hijack then destroy
$session_id = session_id();
session_id($session_id);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

When starting a session, a session ID will be generated and saved as a cookie.

`session_destroy()` will remove the array of `$_SESSION` and thus do the same as `session_unset()`, but in addition it also destroys the session ID. The cookie will be cleared.

From this point, you can only access the `$_SESSION` variable again after starting the session with `session_start()`.